# Ignoring files in Get-ChildItem from objects being loaded from JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I have a script that I am using to read a JSON file, read the paths, calculate the MD5 hash and then export them in a CSV file. The JSON file contains multiple objects. In another post, I laid out the structure of the JSON file and I'll post that here. Please note that I am not allowed to change this JSON.

```
{
"destinationpath": "C:\\Destination\\Mobile Phones\\"
"sourcepath": "C:\\Source\\Mobile Phones\\"
"OnePlus" : {
"files": [
{
"source": "6T",
"destination": "Model\\6T",
"log": "logfiles",
"version": "Version.txt",
}
]
}
"Samsung" : {
"files": [
{
"source": "S20",
"destination": "Galaxy\\S20",
"log": "logfiles",
"version": "Version.txt",
}
]
}
}
```

The `destinationpath: C:\\Destination\\Mobile Phones\\`, when added to, for example, `Samsung` it becomes: `destinationpath: C:\\Destination\\Mobile Phones\\Galaxy\\S20`.

The script that I have so far is this:

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Path file.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSONdestination = $JSON.destination
$JSONsource = $JSON.source


foreach ($i in $JSON.psobject.properties) {
    foreach($i2 in $i.Value ){
        $IgnoredFiles = @(
            $logfiles = $i2.files.log
            $newFiles = $i2.files.version
        )
        $destination = $JSON + $i2.files.destination
        $source = $JSONdestination + $i2.files.source
        echo $destination
        Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse -Exclude $IgnoredFiles | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Export-csv -Append -Path "C:\Users\home\Downloads\hashes.csv"
}
```

In the `Get-ChildItem` portion, I want to exclude the `"log"` and `"version"` files so that they are not counted in the `Get-FileHash`. I have tried doing it this way as well:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse -Exclude $i2.files.log, $i2.files.version | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Export-csv -Append -Path "C:\Users\home\Downloads\hashes.csv"
```

However, it doesn't work either and the `log` and `version` files are still taken into account in the exported csv.

Comment: This can't be right: `$destination = $JSON + $i2.files.destination` since `$JSON` is not part of a path, it is the OBJECT you created when reading `file.json` and converted from json content.

Comment: @Theo Yes, that's a typo. It's actually `$JSONdestination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json you show us is invalid (missing commas and commas too many..)

Once fixed into

```
{
    "destinationpath": "C:\\Destination\\Mobile Phones\\",
    "sourcepath": "C:\\Source\\Mobile Phones\\",
    "OnePlus": {
        "files": [{
            "source": "6T",
            "destination": "Model\\6T",
            "log": "*.log",
            "version": "Version.txt"
        }]
    },
    "Samsung": {
        "files": [{
            "source": "S20",
            "destination": "Galaxy\\S20",
            "log": "*.log",
            "version": "Version.txt"
        }]
    }
}
```

you can do this:

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Path file.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$JSONdestination = $JSON.destinationpath
$JSONsource      = $JSON.sourcepath

$result = foreach ($item in ($JSON | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty destinationpath, sourcepath)) {
    $item.PSObject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object {
        $destPath  = Join-Path -Path $JSONdestination -ChildPath $_.files.destination
        $logFolder = Join-Path -Path $JSONdestination -ChildPath $_.files.log
        $exclude = $_.files.version
        Write-Host "Processing files in '$destPath'" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Get-ChildItem -Path $destPath -Recurse -Exclude $exclude -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
            Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike "$logFolder*" } |
            Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\home\Downloads\hashes.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
`Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Exclude'. Specified method is not supported.`

Comment: @Aithorusa For example, in what you show us, `"log": "logfiles"` doesn't actually fit the bill when it should be used as filename pattern.. That's why I have changed that to become `"log": "*.log"`

Comment: I am using PowerShell 5.1. I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by real life patterns but this JSON file is what is being used. I apologize for my typos and lack of missing commas. I was only making a replica of it so I could get the idea across.
The log and version files work the same way as the destination and source paths(as in getting the full paths from `destinationpath`). Every `Samsung` and `OnePlus` has `log` and `version`. In the creation of the CSV for the hashes, I need to ignore these and only take into account the `destination` files.

Comment: @Aithorusa But it is completely unclear what "log" contains.. `"version"` contains a valid file pattern `Version.txt`, but `"log"` has something like `"logfiles"`. Is that the actual filename, or a **subfolder** we should ignore. What extension do log files have?

Comment: `logfiles` itself is a folder that contains `.txt` files and has subfolders.

Comment: @Aithorusa Please see my edit. Now it considers "log" as a folder instead of a file. (would have been nice if you made that clear to start with)